# Cordova - No Build possible after update to 5.1.1

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, node.js, cordova

I made an update of Cordova from 4.0.2 to 5.1.1 using "npm install -g cordova". Before I developed an App on 4.0.2 and Eclipse IDE. So I tried to create a new project by "cordova create MOsiris com.xyz.mosiris MOsiris", added all plugins as I did before on the old environment and added platform for android by "cordova platform add android".
Then I copied the asset files to the www folder in the root of the project and tried to build by "cordova build" but I always get the following output:

```
C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=D:\AndroidDev\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
Running: C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine wrapper version.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:106)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No build receipt resource found.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.wrapperVersion(GradleWrapperMain.java:92)
    ... 1 more

C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\!!!-WORK-!!!\Inetpub\Android\MOsiris\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\erdoesin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I also tried to delete the project and do the same walk through again two more times. But always with exactly the same effect.

One more thing I recognized on adding the platform: cordova tells me that it added the android platform @4.0.2

```
Copying template files...
Android project created with cordova-android@4.0.2
```

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong? The asset code is OK. It was built successfully on Mac for iOS and on the old 4.0.2 system on PC.

Thank you in advance for your helpful hints and ideas.

Comment: Nobody has an idea? I now tried to create HelloWorld project and adding platform android to it (without adding any plugin). Not even the HelloWorld sample code works... it also gives me the same error output.

Comment: I now updated node.js: node -v = v4.0.0, npm -v = 2.14.2, cordova -v = 5.3.1, ant -v = 1.9.4

Answer (score 3):

So I solved my problem now: There must not be an exclamation mark (!) in the project path.

Now there is another problem...: Gradle has a problem on building when the user path is a network folder. But that is another story.

Hope I could help some of you with this solution.